# Retrieving chisel source description inside of treadle

Tags: scala, code-coverage, chisel

I'm currently working on trying to add coverage to treadle. I was able to do so for the input LoFIRRTL code as follows:

```
COVERAGE REPORT:

+ circuit Test_1 :
+   module Test_1 :
+     input in$a : UInt<1>
+     input in$b$0 : UInt<2>
+     input in$b$1 : UInt<2>
+     input clock : Clock
+     output io_cov_valid_0 : UInt<1>
+     output io_cov_valid_1 : UInt<1>
+     output out : UInt<2>
+   
+     io_cov_valid_0 <= in$a
-     io_cov_valid_1 <= mux(in$a, UInt<1>("h0"), UInt<1>("h1"))
+     out <= mux(in$a, in$b$0, in$b$1)
```

Where `+` means that the line was covered by a test and `-` means that it wasn't. The goal would be to map this information to the Chisel source, which would be more useful.

So is there a way to retrieve the chisel source inside of treadle? If not would there be a pre-existing tool allowing one to reconstruct a Chisel description from LoFIRRTL code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treadle's `symbol`s have an info field which contains (if present) the source locator that references the chisel source. `Mux`s do not have source locators but you the symbol on the left hand side would be the closest you can get. Good luck, I'm happy to answer any Treadle internals questions

Comment: Quick question: What does the `Depend` field of the `symbol`s refer to?

Comment: The cardinalNumber field of a Symbol (shown as "Depend" in rendering) is the location of the symbol in the topologically sorted list of all assignments. Each symbol has a single assignment, the list of assignments for all symbols is how Treadle models circuit execution. The sort is done on a dependency graph built during symbol table construction